# removing string between two words in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

Trying to remove the text between two strings (`/*` and `*/`) in a txt file without deleting full lines.

Lets say I have a file containing the following:

```
/* reports */
%report1(email=first@email.com /*second@email.com */,lag=3);
%report2(email=first@email.com /*second@email.com
third@email.com */ ,lag=3);
```

My desired output would be

```
%report1(email=first@email.com, lag=3);
%report2(email=first@email.com
,lag=3);
```

I have tried many combinations of `tr`, `sed`, and `awk`, but still not working.
Any Thoughts? Notice that report 2 is on two different lines with the delimiters `/*` and `*/` also on separate lines.

Comment: Would you like the last `lag=3`to be behind `%report2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -0777pe 's@/\*.*?\*/@@gs' file.txt
```

Comment: @sputnick so ugly but yet so beautiful!

Comment: Strangely, it does not preserve the original line break (end of line) as requested by the question, in my test.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="/"; ORS="" }\
     /^\*/,/\*$/ { f=1; next }\
     { if (f!=0) f=0; else print "/"; print }' file.txt
```

**Explanation**

`BEGIN { RS="/"; ORS="" }` set the record separator to `"/"`, and the output record separator to an empty string.

`/^\*/,/\*$/ { f=1; next }` skip any records between one that starts with `*`, and one that ends with `*`, while setting flag `f` to 1.

`{ if (f!=0) f=0; else print "/"; print }` if flag `f` is set then unset it, otherwise print `/`, and always print the record.

This **does not** handle the case of `/*` or `*/` occurring in a string.

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='/[*]|[*]/' -v ORS= 'NR%2' file


%report1(email=first@email.com ,lag=3);

%report2(email=first@email.com  ,lag=3);
```